How to define two versions of the same TypedDict, one total and one not?
I’m trying to define two versions of a typed dict for an API client, one total=False for a partial-update route input and another total=True for the response. Any dict with a subset of the fields is valid as an input, but output dicts must have all the fields present.
I tried this:
class PartialDict(TypedDict, total=False):
    name: str
    age: int

class FullDict(PartialDict, total=True):
    pass

But it doesn’t work, as Mypy 1.13 doesn’t complain about any of these:
x: PartialDict = {}  # ok
y: FullDict = {}  # should fail

If I reverse the inheritance and make PartialDict inherit from FullDict that defines the fields, Mypy complains about both lines:
mymodule/types.py:38: error: Missing keys ("name", "age") for TypedDict "PartialDict"  [typeddict-item]
mymodule/types.py:39: error: Missing keys ("name", "age") for TypedDict "FullDict"  [typeddict-item]

How can I define the types such as a FullDict must have all the keys but a PartialDict may not have all of them? I would like to avoid duplicating the classes as my real-world dict has dozens of keys.

Nope, you can't: totality flag was explicitly designed to only affect attributes defined within class body - that was the only way to have a mix of required and optional keys prior to typing.{Required, NotRequired} introduction in 3.11. You'll have to write a mypy plugin (quite a simple one I guess) or repeat the keys twice.

If you're only interested in supporting mypy, then you have enough power to DIY (documentation). Here's a small-ish plugin to implement all_required - a helper that transforms a TypedDict with some optional keys into a TypedDict with all required keys.
(this may not be the optimal way - I could've missed some important details and didn't test this code thoroughly, I rather want this to be an example of what can be done)
# ./tdict_plugin/tdict_plugin/plugin.py
from __future__ import annotations

from typing import Callable

from mypy.errorcodes import MISC
from mypy.nodes import GDEF, NameExpr, SymbolTableNode, TypeInfo
from mypy.plugin import DynamicClassDefContext, Plugin


def all_required_hook(ctx: DynamicClassDefContext) -> None:
    def _fail_with_usage() -> None:
        ctx.api.fail(
            "We only understand all_required(SomeTypedDict) at module level.",
            ctx.call,
            serious=True,
            code=MISC,
        )

    if len(ctx.call.args) != 1:
        return _fail_with_usage()
    original_tdict_expr = ctx.call.args[0]
    if not isinstance(original_tdict_expr, NameExpr):
        return _fail_with_usage()
    original_tdict_info = original_tdict_expr.node
    if not isinstance(original_tdict_info, TypeInfo):
        return _fail_with_usage()
    original_tdict = original_tdict_info.typeddict_type
    if original_tdict is None:
        return _fail_with_usage()
    all_required_tdict = original_tdict.copy_modified(
        required_keys=set(original_tdict.items),
    )

    fallback = ctx.api.named_type(
        "builtins.dict",
        [
            ctx.api.named_type("builtins.str"),
            ctx.api.named_type("builtins.object"),
        ],
    )
    new_info = ctx.api.basic_new_typeinfo(ctx.name, fallback, line=ctx.call.line)
    new_info.update_typeddict_type(all_required_tdict)

    mod = ctx.api.modules[ctx.api.cur_mod_id]
    mod.names[ctx.name] = SymbolTableNode(GDEF, new_info, plugin_generated=True)


class TypedDictPlugin(Plugin):
    def get_dynamic_class_hook(
        self, fullname: str
    ) -> Callable[[DynamicClassDefContext], None] | None:
        if fullname == "tdict_plugin.runtime.all_required":
            return all_required_hook
        return None


def plugin(version: str) -> type[TypedDictPlugin]:
    del version
    return TypedDictPlugin

And runtime part:
# ./tdict_plugin/tdict_plugin/runtime.py
from __future__ import annotations

from typing import TypeVar

_T = TypeVar("_T")


def all_required(cls: _T) -> _T:
    return cls

Since mypy plugins aren't well documented, I'll also post a full example of using this.
Directory structure:
.
├── a.py                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
├── pyproject.toml                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
└── tdict_plugin                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
    ├── pyproject.toml                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    └── tdict_plugin                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
        ├── __init__.py                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
        ├── plugin.py                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
        ├── py.typed                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
        └── runtime.py

a.py is your consumer/testing code like this:
# ./a.py
from typing import TypedDict

from tdict_plugin.runtime import all_required

class PartialDict(TypedDict, total=False):
    name: str
    age: int

FullDict = all_required(PartialDict)

x: PartialDict = {}  # ok
y: FullDict = {}  # should fail
y_ok: FullDict = {"name": "", "age": 0}

Enable the plugin in pyproject.toml (or mypy.ini if you use it):
# ./pyproject.toml
[tool.mypy]
strict = true
plugins = ["tdict_plugin.plugin:plugin"]

py.typed is just an empty file to indicate that tdict_plugin ships with inline type annotations (so that imports from it don't raise mypy error or resolve to Any). tdict_plugin/tdict_plugin/__init__.py is also empty and just indicates a module. Inner pyproject.toml is just the most basic config to install the package:
# ./tdict_plugin/pyproject.toml
[build-system]
requires = ["hatchling"]
build-backend = "hatchling.build"

[project]
name = "tdict_plugin"
version = "0.1.0"
requires-python = ">=3.10"
dependencies = []

Now let's run mypy!
$ mypy a.py
a.py:12: error: Missing keys ("name", "age") for TypedDict "FullDict"  [typeddict-item]
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)

To make this fully reproducible, all steps:
python -m venv .venv
. .venv/bin/activate
pip install mypy
pip install -e ./tdict_plugin
mypy a.py


As noted in this comment, you can't do exactly what you're asking. total  is neither inherited by TypedDict subclasses, nor retroactively applied to the items in their superclasses.
However, if we go back to the question,

Any dict with a subset of the fields is valid as an input, but output dicts must have all the fields present.

This can be imitated. The idea is that the input, while it's being modified, is in the state of total=False, while the output is still non-total but is unioned with a type which prevents removal of any items. Demo (mypy Playground, Pyright Playground):
import typing as t
import collections.abc as cx

type FullDict[T: BaseTypedDict] = T | cx.Mapping[t.Any, t.Any]

class BaseTypedDict(t.TypedDict):
    pass

class PartialDict(t.TypedDict, total=False):
    name: str
    age: int

def populate(td: PartialDict, /) -> FullDict[PartialDict]:
    td["age"] = 20
    return td

>>> x: PartialDict = {"name": "John"}
>>> y: FullDict[PartialDict] = populate(x)
>>>
>>> y['asdfjkl']   # Error: No key "asdfjkl"
>>> del y["age"]   # Error: no method "__delitem__"
>>> y.pop("name")  # Error: no method "pop"


This approach has a very unfortunate problem: y['name'] might be treated as an error as 'name' does not always present in the type PartialDict. That, however, is an implementation detail: "Type checkers may allow reading an item using d['x'] even if the key 'x' is not required, instead of requiring the use of d.get('x') or an explicit 'x' in d check.".

@InSync I understand the motivation behind that, but that would be a rather unergonomic type-checker!
